# Inherit command line parameters to Maven child process

Tags: java, maven, command-line, maven-3

I have a Maven process that starts new child Maven processes (via `maven-verifier`) in the `test` lifecycle phase. The parent process gets invoked with several parameters (e.g. `-s ~/.m2/settings-oss.xml`).

Is there a way to automatically pass/inherit these parameters to the child processes?

-Alexander

Comment: maven-verifier is intended for integration-tests and not for test lifecycle. It sound you would like to run maven itself within tests but that should be done by the maven-invoker-plugin.

Comment: I'm running Maven with integration tests and not unit tests.

Comment: Than you should use maven-invoker-plugin.

Comment: What is the problem with maven-verifier?

Comment: I didn't said there is a problem but you are talking about executing integration-tests via maven-verifier which will not work cause maven-verifier is only to test certain conditions and not running tests itself. How are you starting your child processes for testing ?

Comment: `Verifier verifier = new Verifier("test base dir"); verifier.executeGoal("deploy");`

Comment: Ah I see. Misunderstand between test-harness and the plugin Ok.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help:

```
verifier.getCliOptions().add("-DmyParameter=v1");
verifier.executeGoal( "package" );
```